# Tangent space of the space of smooth sections of a bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, frechet-manifold

Let $E\to M$ be a real vector bundle of finite rank over a closed differentiable manifold $M$. Let $C^{\infty}(E)$ denote the space of smooth sections of $E$ and let $e\in C^{\infty}(E)$ be a section. I often see statements of the type:

"The tangent space to $C^{\infty}(E)$ at any given section $e\in C^{\infty}(E)$ is isomorphic to $C^{\infty}(E)$ itself, namely $T_{e}C^{\infty}(E)\simeq C^{\infty}(E)$."

I wonder what is the precise formulation of the statement above.

I know that if we only take smooth sections, $C^{\infty}(E)$ admits the structure of an infinite dimensional Frechet manifold with respect to the appropriate topology. The statement should be then that the isomorphism $T_{e}C^{\infty}(E)\simeq C^{\infty}(E)$ holds understanding $C^{\infty}(E)$ as a Frechet manifold and taking $T_{e}C^{\infty}(E)$ to be the tangent space of $C^{\infty}(E)$ as a Frechet manifold? Or rather, should it be understood by assuming that we have implicitly Sobolev-completed $C^{\infty}(E)$ into $H_{s}(E)$ using some appropriate Sobolev norm as to make $H_{s}(E)$ into a smooth Hilbert manifold and then the isomorphism that actually holds is  $T_{e}H_{s}(E)\simeq H_{s}(E)$?

My second question is: can one make sense of an isomorphism of the type $T_{e}C^{\infty}(E)\simeq C^{\infty}(E)$ if the base is non-compact?

And lastly, let $Q\to M$ be a smooth fiber bundle over a closed manifold $M$ with typical fiber $F$ given by a smooth manifold. How should be understood the tangent space at a point of the space of sections of $Q$?

References are welcome.

Comment: Concerning the last question: a tangent vector to a given section $s$ would probably be a vertical vector field in $Q$ along the section $s$ (vertical wrt the projection $Q\to M$ ). Unfortunately I don't have a reference.

Answer (score 10):

$C^\infty(E)$ is a Frechet VECTOR space. Thus its tangent space at each point equals $C^\infty(E)$ via its affine structure.

## Added:

This is also true if $M$ is not compact. However, for a fiber bundle $Q\to M$ one has to be more careful with the topology (if $M$ is not compact). See 10.10  of

- Peter W. Michor: Manifolds of differentiable mappings. Shiva Mathematics Series 3, Shiva Publ., Orpington, (1980) [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf)

for an answer. In principle, the tangent space is the space of sections of the vertical bundle of $Q$ restricted to the the image of a section.
There is also Sections 42, 43, .. of

- Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor: The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, Volume: 53, American Mathematical Society, Providence, 1997 [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/apbookh-ams.pdf)

where a more easily handable notion of differentiability is developped and then used.

These methods also work for Sobolev spaces of sections. See

- MR3135704 Reviewed
  Inci, H.; Kappeler, T.; Topalov, P.
  On the regularity of the composition of diffeomorphisms. (English summary)
  Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 226 (2013), no. 1062, vi+60 pp.

for the basics of these.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. If you can add some remarks about the other points in the question, I would appreciate it. In particular, is your remark true if $M$ is non-compact?

Comment: @Peter having finally bought a physical copy of your book (one I ordered first was lost in transit!) I do wonder whether you'd consider making it available via print on demand publishing.